# maximum recursion depth exceeded on logout(request)

Tags: django

I'm trying to create the logout functionality on my page. But getting this recursion error, everytime I hit the link that points to the logout url.

Below is the code, for what is suppose to be showing content and a logout functionality if the user is logged in. Otherwise show the login form.

view methods

```
def login(request):

   username = request.POST.get('username')
   password = request.POST.get('password')

   user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

   context = {

   }

   if user is not None:
       print('Correct user'   
   else:
       print('Wrong user')

       return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def logout(request):
    print('logged out')
    logout(request)

    return redirect('index')
```

url

```
urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),         

            url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'), 

            url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

index.html

```
    {% if user %}
        <h3>Hello {{user.username}}</h3>
        <a href="{% url 'crowd:logout' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'crowd:login' %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input class='logintext' type='text' placeholder='Username' name='username'>
            <input class='logintext' type='password' placeholder='Password' name='password'><br>
            <input class='loginbutton' type='submit' value='Login'>
            <a class='loginforgotpassword' href="{% url 'crowd:register' %}"> Forgot password?</a>
            <a class='loginregister' href="{% url 'crowd:register' %}"> Register</a>
        </form>
    {% endif%}
```

console error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\views.py", line 48, in logout
    logout(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\views.py", line 48, in logout
    logout(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\views.py", line 48, in logout
    logout(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\views.py", line 47, in logout
    print('logged out')
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
[04/Sep/2016 23:35:59] "GET /Crowd/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 3210436
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kindly change name of your logout view.

The error is with:

```
def logout(request):
    print('logged out')
    logout(request)

    return redirect('index')
```

your view name is logout with request parameter. so when you call logout(request) in the view, it calls your logout view not Django's logout function. that's causing recursion.

Comment: No problem. We've all been here in our lives :)

Comment: What a silly mistake i never realized